# Most efficient way in C++ to strip strings

Tags: c++, strings, algorithm, homework

If I want to strip a string completely of its **whitespaces, punctuation and numbers** (i.e. anything that is not A-Z, a-z), what is the most efficient way of doing it in C++?

I tried this:

```
string strip(string in) {
    string final;
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if(isalpha(in[i])) final += in[i];
    }
    return final;
}
```

It works as expected, but is too slow on strings with ~2000 characters. I figured out that the code causing this slowness is the `isalpha()` call.

So does anyone know of a better, more efficient way of stripping a string of everything except [A-Z][a-z] in C++?

At most, the string will be 20000 characters long and I need to strip it in <1 second.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

If I remove the `if` condition, the output will display instantly. But *with* the `if` condition, it will take about 1.6 seconds to display the output.

For trying out the code, use this: http://pastebin.com/g3NtBFaD and a normal 20k char string. Then try comparing.

Comment: How fast/slow is your computer? Using a normal machine with about 100 mil ops per second, I think 2000 chars should be short enough.

Comment: If this code doesn't run in < 1 second for 2000 character long strings you must be sitting on a c64 or something ;)

Comment: The testing server is a Pentium III 800MHz computer..

Comment: Replace isAlpha with your own comparisons perhaps, although I suspect it may be your += on the string that takes a while if you're not reserving capacity in advance.

Comment: Push the 'Turbo' button :)

Comment: @Roshnal: Do you have an equally old compiler? Because that could also be a problem.

Comment: On my computer, I have Ubuntu 11.04 with GCC 4.6 and my processor is 2.8GHz dual core.

Comment: The other posts about reserving space in advance for the output are valid but, even so, 2000 chars - shoud not remotely approach a second.

Comment: @MartinJames I also thought about that, but it takes a while before showing me the output. But _if_ I remove the `isalpha()` part, the output would display instantly..

Comment: @Roshnal: Show us the rest of your code.

Comment: Could you try a profiler?

Comment: Do you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: OK, so what if you code the IsAlpha yourself, if((in[i]>="A"&&in[i]<="Z")||(in[i]>="a"&&in[i]<="z"))...

Comment: I honestly cannot imagine how this task can possibly take you so long. It's a relatively simple test on a small source string.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Don't know, its an automatic tester in USACO

Comment: @MartinJames Tried that.. Still takes long

Comment: @DeadMG Can you please try the above code? Try inputting a 2000char string with and without the "isalpha" checking.

Comment: @Martin.  Ouch! multiple calls to `std::string::operator[]` in that expression.  isalpha() tests by testing the bit pattern against a mask rather than numeric ranges (for ACSII encoding at least); it will be much faster.  I suspect that that is not where the problem truly lies.

Comment: @Clifford - I would have thought that it would be optimized to index the char only once.  Even so, we are back to 'how can doing anything with a char take 500us?'.

Comment: Ae we going to have to optimize this into pointer arithmetic?

Comment: @Martin James I already did ;)

Comment: @Roshnal: On my machine (i7 930 2.8GHz Windows 7 64bit), in Release mode, it takes so little time, even after increasing the timer resolution to *nanoseconds*, I still came back with 0. I had to compare the CPU cycle count to get a time- 1080 cycles.

Comment: @DeadMG Yes I also tried with other test cases each with 2000chars. And they took 0.000 to 0.010 seconds to execute. But this: http://ace.delos.com/usacodatashow?a=AHnzwbDqkIc takes a lot of time.

Comment: @Roshnal: That page won't open for me. In addition, I used virtually your exact code from the OP- not a different test case.

Comment: @Roshnal The server at ace.delos.com is taking too long to respond :D

Comment: @AndreasBrinck - Oh yeah... sorry!  It's just that this problem is very vexing!  I would have said that a character-range check operation on only 2000 characters would only take 1.6 seconds if run on an abacus, and then only if the beads are sticking.

Comment: Sorry, try this http://pastebin.com/g3NtBFaD

Comment: That document has 20k chars, but still if I remove the `if` condition, it would display instantly. If not, it will take 1.6 seconds

Comment: @Roshnal That string is 20000 chars, not 2000. But still runs in a blink of an eye.

Comment: @Andrey Yeah, sorry for the wrong info, but did you try enabling/disabling the `if` condition and see what happens?

Comment: @Roshnal No difference.

Comment: I think this is not a matter of "the most efficient way" as teh title asks; your way is not the most efficient, but it certainly should not take that long - something else is wrong.

Comment: @Roshnal if you remove the `if` condition the compiler might be smart enough to just `return in;`...

Comment: @Andrey But it does make a difference on my computer and the testing computer. The execution time will completely change with the enabling/disabling of the `if` condition...

Comment: @Roshnal See my previous comment

Comment: @AndreasBrinck I hope not.. Even with the `final += in[i]`, it executes in the blink of an eye

Comment: @Roshnal Did you try with a lookup table?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck No, can you please provide a code sample?

Comment: Try replacing the `isalpha` with a really trivial condition, say `i % 5` and see what happens

Answer (score 17):

A few thoughts which come to my mind, without having actually profiled your code:

1. Try passing `std::string` as reference-to-const to avoid a copy (in case your `std::string` implementation is not Copy-On-Write).
2. Reserve space in the `std::string` by calling `reserve`.
3. Avoid calling `std::string::length` repeatedly, memorize the value.
4. Avoid indexing the string repeatedly, use an iterator instead.

For what it's worth, you could try a different (more functional) way to implement this function. Some may consider this idiomatic, other will find it harder to read. Your call -maybe just for the fun of it, to see how it performs (remember to enable optimizations!):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <locale>
#include <string>

std::string strip( const std::string &s ) {
    std::string result;
    result.reserve( s.length() );

    std::remove_copy_if( s.begin(),
                         s.end(),
                         std::back_inserter( result ),
                         std::not1( std::ptr_fun( isalpha ) ) );

    return result;
}
```

Comment: "in case your std::string implementation is not Copy-On-Write" -- none that I know of is. "Avoid calling std::string::length repeatedly, memorize the value." -- this is a non-issue, the lookup is constant. "Avoid indexing the string repeatedly, use an iterator instead." -- non-issue aswell, it's a simple read. Iterators and indexing are both equally fast. And if you're going for the functional-y route, please don't use function pointers. They slow down the code considerably as opposed to function objects.

Comment: @Xeo: According to http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/strings.html  libstdc++'s string is Copy-On-Write. No idea to which version(s) it applies. Regarding O(1) complexity of `std::string::length` - that's only what's *specified* but maybe the OP's implementation is flawed (there seems to be something fishy given how slow it is).  Same is true for your other comments, just because *most* implementations comply to the specifications, this is not true for all of them (and I'm saying this as somebody who hsa to use MSVC6 a lot...).

Comment: @Xeo: In general, any sufficiently old compiler will trigger every bug in the standard (template) libraries you can think of. So be careful when taking things for granted. ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: personally, I care little for outdated compilers. Still, your solution is the fastest that I tested (redefining `isalpha` and using an inline predicate). Which is comforting me that theory does help, since it's perhaps the most conservative with regard to memory allocation and copies.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: Glad to hear that increasing the level of abstraction actually improves the runtime efficiency of the code for a change. ;-)

Answer (score 10):

I would add a:

```
final.reserve(in.length());
```

to avoid allocations when doing the `+=`.

You could try this code, but I doubt it will be much faster:

```
string strip(const string& in) {
    char final[2000];
    char* cursor = final;
    for(string::const_iterator c = in.begin(), end = in.end(); c != end; ++c) {
        char cc = *c;
        if ((cc >= 'a' && cc <= 'z') || (cc >= 'A' && cc <= 'Z'))
        {
            *cursor = cc;
            ++cursor;
        }
    }
    *cursor = 0;
    return final;
}
```

Notice that the `in` parameter is now passed by reference. One possible, though unlikely, improvement would be to create a 256 `bool` lookup table that stores if a given char is alpha:

```
string strip(const string& in) {
    bool lut[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < 256; ++i)
    {
        lut[i] = (i >= 'a' && i <= 'z') || (i >= 'A' && i <= 'Z');
    }
    string final;
    final.reserve(in.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
        if (lut[in[i]]) final += in[i];
    }
    return final;
}
```

Note that the LUT is populated everytime this code is called, if the string is > 20.000 this time should be insignificant though.

Comment: Tried that, no improvement...

Comment: Still takes as much as long. But if I remove the `if` condition (which checks for A-Z a-z) its really fast..

Comment: @Roshnal Try it with a lookup table, might be faster.

Comment: @Clifford No, I suspect it's something else as well.

Comment: If the string is indeed Unicode, it would beed either a very large lookup table or some implicit conversions to char.  Even if the string is Unicode, 2000 characters is.. not that many.  How could it take a human-noticeable time?

Comment: @MartinJames: That's what I'm thinking. How on earth can the CPU fail to process such a small string in a short time?

Comment: It seems so unnecessary to limited yourself to a 2000 characters long array when a dynamically sized vector/string would do the deed.

Comment: @DeadMG I think he's running this code on a remote testing computer, so I don't think he's getting 1 second of CPU time.

Comment: I'm doing USACO and this is a problem in section 1.3. It says for test case 8 (i.e. a string with 2000chars) it takes 1.6 seconds to complete. I tried it on my computer also, and yes, it does take 1.6 seconds...

Comment: @Roshnal How do you measure the time? You should be able to run your code on a 1000000 character long string on your computer in < 1 second.

Comment: I just noticed that all other test cases run fine (in 0.000 seconds to 0.010 seconds) **except** this: http://ace.delos.com/usacodatashow?a=AHnzwbDqkIc

Comment: Given that `isalpha()` probably tests by bitmask rather than numeruc range, I suggest that it will be faster than this expression.  The fact that the change makes no difference, suggests that the execution time for both is insignificant.

Comment: @Roshnal I can't access that. Can you add the offending string to your question?

Comment: @AndreasBrinck Its really large. I'll use pastebin to post it here.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck http://pastebin.com/g3NtBFaD

Comment: Sorry, that document has 20,000 chars.. But still?

Comment: Sorry, but why the 256 and what's the cc?

Comment: The `cc` was just a typo when I copied the code, and 256 is the number of different values for a `char`.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck No I meant from where is cc coming? You have directly used cc >=... and it gives me an error.

Comment: @Roshnal Reload my answer, in the second version of the code there's no reference to `cc`.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck OK, but for some reason, it gives an error in the `lut[in[i]]` code.

Comment: @Roshnal: You would have to say *what the error is*.

Comment: @DeadMG No, no error. But still it takes as much time.

Comment: If I remove the lut-assigning part, it executes really fast. So I think the problem is with checking for alpha-characters (with or without `isalpha` method.

Answer (score 7):

You may try following C++11 code which allocates memory and changes the final string size only once

```
std::string strip(std::string in) 
  {
  in.erase(std::remove_if(in.begin(), in.end(), [] (std::string::value_type ch)
      { return !isalpha(ch); }
    ), in.end());
  return in;
  }
```

Comment: You mean except in the unnecessary copy in the argument?

Comment: @DeadMG I can eliminate that copy, taking into account that `in` is passed by value

Comment: If the argument is an lvalue, you just unnecessarily copied it. There is no reason to take by vaue here because you do not need to own the argument string.

Comment: Gives me an error in the `, in.end()` part..

Comment: @Roshnal Tested in VC2010. If your compiler doesn't support C++11, you have to replace the lambda with a predicate.

Comment: @Andrey How was it?

Comment: @Roshnal: does your compiler support lambdas ?

Comment: @Roshnal yes, it supports lambdas, and the result is instant even in debug. You really should profile your code.

Comment: calfflac.cpp: In function ‘std::string strip(std::string)’:
calfflac.cpp:37:94: warning: lambda expressions only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x
calfflac.cpp:37:95: error: no matching function for call to ‘remove_if(std::basic_string<char>::iterator, std::basic_string<char>::iterator, strip(std::string)::<lambda(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::value_type)>)’

Comment: @Andrey Sorry I don't know what's lambda.. I'm a complete beginner to C++

Comment: @Roshnal Perhaps, you have to use `-std=c++0x` compiler switch to enable lambdas?

Comment: @Roshnal Look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#C.2B.2B

Comment: The only issue with this version is the initial copy. If the string is only sparsely populated with alphabetic characters, then a big memory allocation and large copy are done... for nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another benchmark, showing yet another possibility that may be worth considering, if you can:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <limits.h>

class not_isalpha {
    bool table[UCHAR_MAX];
public:
    not_isalpha() {
        for (int i=0; i<UCHAR_MAX; i++)
            table[i] = !isalpha(i);
    }

    bool operator()(char input){
        return table[(unsigned char)input];
    }
};

template <class T>
T gen_random(size_t len) {
    T x;
    x.reserve(len);

    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(x), len, rand);
    return x;
}

template <class Container, class stripper>
clock_t test(Container const &input, Container &result, stripper strip) {   
    result.reserve(input.size());
    clock_t start = clock();
    std::remove_copy_if(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(result), strip);
    return clock() - start;
}

void show(std::string const &label, clock_t ticks) {
    std::cout << label << ": " << ticks/(double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " Seconds\n";
}

int main(){
    typedef std::vector<char> T;
    static const size_t size = 50000000; 

    T x(gen_random<T>(size));
    T result;

    show("not_isalpha, vector", test(x, result, not_isalpha()));
    show("::isalpha, vector", test(x, result, std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isalpha))));

    std::string input2(x.begin(), x.end());
    std::string result2;

    show("not_isalpha, string", test(input2, result2, not_isalpha()));
    show("::isalpha, string", test(input2, result2, std::not1(std::ptr_fun(isalpha))));

    return 0;
}
```

At least in my testing, with both VC++ (10), and g++ (4.7.0), `std::vector` comes out faster than string.

VC++ 10:

```
not_isalpha, vector: 0.246 Seconds
::isalpha, vector: 0.401 Seconds
not_isalpha, string: 0.473 Seconds
::isalpha, string: 0.631 Seconds
```

g++ 4.7.0:

```
not_isalpha, vector: 0.212 Seconds
::isalpha, vector: 0.382 Seconds
not_isalpha, string: 0.285 Seconds
::isalpha, string: 0.413 Seconds
```

Using our own table-driven version of `isalpha` helps speed quite a bit compared to using `::isalpha`, but using `std::vector` improves speed even more, especially with VC++ (though the difference is *fairly* substantial with g++ as well).

For those who like to compare compilers, it's worth noting that g++ is not only faster overall, but also more consistently fast. With g++, the worst case is only about two times slower than the fastest. With VC++, the worst case is about three times slower.

Answer (score 3):

Use the C locale. On some locales, `isalpha` and friends might be very slow.

E.g. on UNIX

```
LANG=C
export LANG
```

or use std::locale to activate the C locale from code

```
std::locale::global(std::locale::classic); // untested draft
```

**Background**

For an example of how locales can slowdown performance of e.g. UNIX `sort(1)` by a factor of 20x, see this old answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124489/unix-sort-command-takes-much-longer-depending-on-where-it-is-executed-fastest/7150015#7150015

Comment: @Roshnal can you provide any feedback on this? In all fairness I think this was unjustly moved to codereview, and, though interesting, all micro-optimization beyond `final.reserve(in.size())` smells like premature optimization.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, one needs to use benchmarks.

An idiomatic C++ solution is likely to be better optimized, so Andrey's and Frerich's solutions are both strong contenders.

The code exposed below gives the following results with gcc 4.3.2 and -O2:

- Input1: `"afoiahge m8hfw fewu8 n  hv ghwvoiwbegh2390ty3t80ytgh8ghng8hg24u8b vh2vn289vh2gh28g9jfhfuweghwu2hbvgfw22ghb84ty2bgv2nfbukbvsdbvwuivbnbvbnn hf wgwg  gwev wgbv23t4 1sv4gbwer14hh414ernhe 01e4g 1e 1h4ghwerh14re e4hj 14yv y344yjd1vh h 1e6"`
- Input2: the string you proposed
- Original: 1: 3268, 2: 138894
- From Andrey's: 1: 1243, 2: 65469
- From Frerich's: 1: 1965, 2: 140818

Therefore, Andrey's solution offers a solid 2x speed up over your proposed solution. Much better.

Their strategy differ though, because Andrey copies the whole string in one swoop and then removes the parts that do not fit, while Frerich only copy the right parts to begin with.

I would select Frerich's approach (despite it being stlightly slower here), just to avoid large unused copies if memory is a concern. Note that if you have an inkling about the distribution, then you can adjust the amount of memory reserved.

Code:

```
#include <sys/time.h>

#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

namespace bench {

  template <typename Func>
  double benchmark(Func f, size_t iterations)
  {
    f();

    timeval a, b;
    gettimeofday(&a, 0);
    for (; iterations --> 0;)
    {
      f();
    }
    gettimeofday(&b, 0);
    return (b.tv_sec * (unsigned int)1e6 + b.tv_usec) -
           (a.tv_sec * (unsigned int)1e6 + a.tv_usec);
  }

}

namespace test {

  bool isalpha(char c) { return (c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z'); }
  bool notalpha(char c) { return not isalpha(c); }

  struct NotAlpha {
    bool operator()(char c) { return notalpha(c); }
  };

  // Roshal
  std::string strip1(std::string const& in) {
      std::string final;
      for(size_t i = 0; i < in.length(); i++) {
          if(isalpha(in[i])) final += in[i];
      }
      return final;
  }

  // Andrey
  std::string strip2(std::string const& s) {
    std::string in = s;
    in.erase(std::remove_if(in.begin(), in.end(), NotAlpha()), in.end());
    return in;
  }

  // Frerich Raabe
  std::string strip3( const std::string &s ) {
    std::string result;
    result.reserve( s.length() );

    std::remove_copy_if( s.begin(),
                         s.end(),
                         std::back_inserter( result ),
                         NotAlpha() );

    return result;
  }

} // namespace test

namespace bench {
  struct Stripper {
    typedef std::string (*Func)(std::string const&);

    Stripper(Func f, std::string const& s): _func(f), _s(s) {}

    void operator()() { _func(_s); }

    Func const _func;
    std::string const _s;
  };
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  std::string const ref = argc == 1 ? "Let's make an example" : argv[1];

  bench::Stripper s1(test::strip1, ref);
  bench::Stripper s2(test::strip2, ref);
  bench::Stripper s3(test::strip3, ref);

  double const r1 = benchmark(s1, 1000);
  double const r2 = benchmark(s2, 1000);
  double const r3 = benchmark(s3, 1000);

  std::cout << "1: " << r1 << "\n";
  std::cout << "2: " << r2 << "\n";
  std::cout << "3: " << r3 << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Can you post the test result using the worst case string included in the OP?

Comment: I guess that, just for the record, you should verify that the solutions you benchmark actually produce the same results.

Comment: Furthermore, in `benachmark`, you call `f()` up front - why is that? Finally, your program doesn't run my solution at all. Both `s2` and `s3` use `test::strip2`. If you actually run my version, you will see that it's much slower. So I'd actually go for Andrey's version.

Comment: Andrey’s original code was better than your adaptation because it passes the argument by value to take advantage of move construction from temporaries. Oh, and +1 for ISO 646 keywords.

Comment: @AndreasBrinck: done. It's a alpha string so unsurprisingly Andrey's solution performs very well.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe: Sorry for the slip, I edited the code. I call the function up front before benchmarking as a cache warm-up.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: using gcc 4.3.2 for this benchmark, move operations are not a concern. Therefore I edited the signature so that it would match that of the two other functions.

Answer (score 2):

Try calling reserve(2000) on your final string before using it. Also take a const ref as argument.

Edit:

I would suspect that on Unix, the `isalpha` function is performing a lot more work to support Unicode, and you are only interested in the ASCII range. It's still a big leap, but you might try replacing it with a custom comparison, like `if ((in[i] <= 'Z' && in[i] >= 'A') || (in[i] >= 'a' && in[i] <= 'z'))`.

Comment: Nope, no improvement..

Comment: Still its slow (no improvement whatsoever)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that it is not the `isalpha()` call that is taking the time but rather the two `std::string::operator[]` calls and/or the `std::string::operator+=` call.

You could probably speed this loop up by using an iterator to reference `in`, thus avoiding `std::string::operator[]`, and appending the character will be faster using `std::string::push_back` and if you initially expanding `final` to have the same initial capacity as `in`.

Passing the unmodified input string as a const reference may also help but will only be significant if you are calling the function itself iteratively.

```
string strip( const string& in) 
{
    final.reserve( in.length() ) ;
    string::iterator it;
    for ( it=str.begin() ; it < str.end(); it++ )
    {
        if( isalpha( *it ) )
        {
            final.push_back( *it ) ;
        }
    }

    return final  ;
}
```

All that said, I strongly suggest that your use the profiler or add timing instrumentation to the code to reveal the true performance hog.  The timings you suggest do not seem likely - something else is happening here I think.

Comment: No, when I only remove the `if` condition in the shown code, the output is instantly shown, _even if_ the `final += in[i]` part is still there.

Comment: @Roshnal:  Possibly because the compiler can optimise it out to a string copy.  If the call assigns the string to itself, it might even optimise out the call altogether (if it were very smart).  Something is wrong here; isalpha() is a very simple function (in fact it is a macro, so you can see what it does in the ctype.h file).

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick method.  Maybe a bit naughty writing directly into the string contents, but the new c++ standard guarantees that the string will be contiguous (according to another stackoverflow post).

```
inline bool isAZaz(char ch) {
    return (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z');
}

void strip(std::string const& s, std::string* result)
{
    result->clear();
    if (s.empty()) {
        return;
    }
    result->resize(s.size());

    char ch;
    char const* p = s.c_str();
    char const* e = p + s.size();
    char* o = &(*result)[0];
    char const* r = o;
    for (; p < e; ++p) {
        ch = *p;
        if (isAZaz(ch)) {
            *o++ = (ch);
        }
    }
    result->resize(o - r);
}
```

Executes in 0.000037 seconds on my PC, compared to 0.000759 for your original method, so roughly 20 times faster.  using ::isalpha instead of a handwritten check takes 0.000096 seconds (3x slower my version).

Comment: What are you doing here?! Just use iterators instead of pointers. Why do you pass the argument as a pointer? Unorthodox, error-prone and unnecessary. Why do you declare `ch` outside of the loop? And while I agree that using iterators is nice, it won’t change the the performance – at least not nearly as drastic as observed by you.  That’s probably due to the removal of an unnecessary copy and avoiding `isalpha`. Oh, and the code is UB if the string is empty.

Comment: You can thank Microsoft for the poor iterator performance on visual studio compiler.  the fact of the matter is that the correct way of doing things often isn't optimal.  Yes perhaps a check for empty strings is an idea to prevent an exception accessing element zero.  I think your point that using iterators won't change performance as much as I have observed by actually profiling the code is a little naive.

Comment: Oh, and passing the output parameter as a pointer makes it more obvious that it is an output parameter in calling code.  See the Qt coding guidelines.

Comment: Iterators on strings *are* just `char*` when you compile with optimisations enabled. Going to Qt for coding guidelines is like going to the pope for the pill. Don’t use `out` parameters at all, use return values. VS (and every other modern compiler) optimises this. As for pointer-versus-index, there is virtually no difference. Again, this is optimised anyway.

Comment: On the Visual Studio compiler a string iterator IS NOT a char*.  Perhaps it is on GCC, which the OP is using (have you checked?).  If it is, then he might as well use iterators, but the fact you've pointed out that it is the same leads me to wonder why it matters?  On VS, incrementing and dereferencing an iterator is a function call in RELEASE mode.  You only need to look at the ASM output to see this.  As for coding guidelines, this is not really applicable to the OP's question, which is asking how to optimize the function.

Comment: Added check for empty string, as this is a valid point.

Comment: On VS, you can turn off _SECURE_SCL, but this leads to a whole host of other problems if STL is used in libraries that don't do the same.

Comment: And he is on GCC anyway.

Comment: OP should profile the code.

Comment: Also, as for the return value, if you have a local string that is returned, it often will be a copy, not all compilers apply the RVO to this, only if the string is constructed as part of the return statement.

Comment: *All* modern compilers implement NRVO. As for using `_SECURE_SCL ≠ 0` … well, people who have to care about this have my deepest sympathy (I’m serious). Microsoft did developers a huge disservice with this feature.

Comment: I'd have to agree with you there.  Sometimes you have to be pragmatic, especially when optimizing.  If you were to manually vectorize this loop, then you would have to use pointers...